# Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7

Tags: android, android-support-library

Everything was working fine unless on a bad day I changed the workspace, followed by updating the SDK. Now I get the following error:

```
06-10 13:03:54.554: I/dalvikvm(3561): Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor, referenced from method com.exa.digitalanniversaries.MainActivity.initdata
06-10 13:03:54.554: W/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12514: Landroid/view/Window;.setStatusBarColor (I)V
06-10 13:03:54.554: D/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0026
06-10 13:03:54.659: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.659: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.663: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11; (1150)
06-10 13:03:54.663: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.667: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14; (1136)
06-10 13:03:54.667: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.667: E/dalvikvm(3561): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create
06-10 13:03:54.671: W/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1138 (Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14;) in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;
06-10 13:03:54.671: D/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
06-10 13:03:54.671: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.671: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.671: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11; (1150)
06-10 13:03:54.671: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.671: E/dalvikvm(3561): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create
06-10 13:03:54.671: W/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1136 (Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11;) in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;
06-10 13:03:54.671: D/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
06-10 13:03:54.675: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.675: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.675: E/dalvikvm(3561): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create
06-10 13:03:54.679: W/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1150 (Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;) in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;
06-10 13:03:54.679: D/dalvikvm(3561): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0016
06-10 13:03:54.682: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11; (1150)
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14; (1136)
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV14;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.682: D/dalvikvm(3561): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x205a at 0x08 in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;.create
06-10 13:03:54.682: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.682: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.686: W/dalvikvm(3561): Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11; (1150)
06-10 13:03:54.686: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV11;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.686: D/dalvikvm(3561): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2055 at 0x12 in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;.create
06-10 13:03:54.690: I/dalvikvm(3561): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7; interface 773 'Landroid/support/v4/view/LayoutInflaterFactory;'
06-10 13:03:54.690: W/dalvikvm(3561): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7;' failed
06-10 13:03:54.690: D/dalvikvm(3561): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2093 at 0x18 in Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate;.create
06-10 13:03:54.694: D/AndroidRuntime(3561): Shutting down VM
06-10 13:03:54.694: W/dalvikvm(3561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c10300)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:93)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:429)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.exa.digitalanniversaries.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:558)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-10 13:03:54.729: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried everything from manually adding all libs again, to downloading the v7 lib afresh and then integrating it into the project. It does not seem that I have exceeded the 65k limit on methods as the first three pages of my app work fine and the error only occurs when I switch to an Activity which extends AppCompactActivity or ActionBarActivity. I have literally tried everything listed here on SO, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the image of my private libs, v7 is clearly listed, so I think this is not an issue with imports:

[image]

Comment: After much struggle, pain and perseverance I imported this project into Android studio, there were a 100 errors and warings due to importing a non studio project, resolved them and all seems fine I just ran this project :)